# Getting Node.appendChild error with leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to add a popup function to some polygons. I've been consulting a few different tutorials trying to work it out and I'm concerned that I am getting conflicting instructions.

The map I have now is displaying perfectly. The next step for me is to add the popup when the polygon is clicked on. I keep getting the error "Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object." I have no idea what this means. My only guess is that it has something to do with using a var within landscape.js to create the landscape.geojson, since that might not be creating it in the right way to use it for the popup.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./leaflet/leaflet.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="./leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="landscape.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id=map></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var map = L.map('map').setView([42.505, -100], 3);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>',
subdomains: 'abcd',
maxZoom: 19
}).addTo(map);

function toAddPopup (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.metro_severePct);
        }

L.geoJson(landscape,{
        onEachFeature: toAddPopup
}).addTo(map);

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `layer.bindPopup` method is expecting a string, but you are passing it a numeric property. You can avoid the error by either using `.toString()`:

```
function toAddPopup (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.metro_severePct.toString());
        }
```

or by appending your property to another string using the `+` operator, which will also convert the numeric value to a string:

```
function toAddPopup (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup('Percent severe:' + feature.properties.metro_severePct);
        }
```

Comment: Brilliant! There's nothing in the tutorials about that, so thank you for the insight. Is there a way to check what it's expecting?

Comment: It's in the [Leaflet docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html) if you know where to look. You will see that [L.geoJson](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson) doesn't list any method for `.bindPopup`, but it extends (and thus inherits the methods from) [L.featureGroup](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup), which does have a `.bindPopup` method accepting a string and an optional popup options object as arguments.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the added info. I'm guessing that knowing where to look in the documentation might come in handy at some point in the future, too.